# Windows 8.1 evaluation version sets the resolution to 1024X768

Tags: windows-8, display, windows-8.1-preview, windows-8.1

Windows 8.1 evaluation version sets the resolution to 1024X768 and is not letting me change it. Although my Laptop supports 1366X768. How can I change it as the icons are looking too big and the user experience is bad. Any help will be useful.

Comment: It sounds likely that you have a display driver problem. Try reinstalling it from scratch, from your graphics card's website. (if it's onboard graphics like in so many laptops and you can't for the life of you figure it out, there's a good chance it's Intel or AMD, same as the motherboard/processor.

Answer (score 0):

you just have to install display driver for your graphic card.